# LinkedIn REST API call to check my competitor posts

Tags: linkedin-api

I can't find the right answer on Linkedin API docs. I'm searching for a request for seeing my competitor posts and likes. Do you know if there is a way to obtain that data?

From my research seems that you can only get your company's posts and not other users posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO, you can only see data you belong or have access through role permission.